# Finding file locks in legacy c# code

Tags: c#, debugging, file-locking

I have an interesting problem - I've inherited a large code base (brown field).

The application runs on a schedule and takes a large amount of data files (text) in, processes them, and then exports a report and cleans up.

There is a bug that has been discovered whereby when trying to clean up afterwards, some files are left in a `locked` state, even though all file activity has long gone out of scope. This stops the application from being able to delete them during clean up.

There are literally hundreds of IO and stream objects etc being used in this application, and I'm wanting to find out where to start looking to save reviewing every instance of their use.

What are some good tools for investigating File locks in c# managed code, and how do you use them to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor file access (read/write) using [**ProcMon**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals.
Its not specific to c# but a general tool that can be used for many other things. Note you can export the results to csv and investigate it later.

You can use one of the following guides:

- [Detailed Windows I/O: Process Monitor](http://sqlvelocity.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/detailed-windows-io-process-monitor.html) - How to do simple file monitoring.
- [Using Process Monitor to Monitor File Access](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-Process-Monitor-to-Monitor-File-Access) - More detailed guide explaining how to export the results into a csv you can investigate later.

**Edit:**

I didn't found anything for this purpose, so if I was you I would inherit from the steam used, and wrap it with logging logic.

This logging stream object, for example named `LogStream` will write log before each method entrance, call the `base.function()` and write another log when done.

This way you can monitor the file access as you wish. For example, logging each stream instance an Id using `Guid.NewGuid()`, logging Thread Id using `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` etc.

This way you can identify the instances and slowly investigate the calls.

A point to start is to check whether there is equal number both stream open and close, an exception might avoided one of the `Dispose()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've already been using ProcMon. Sadly it'll only tell me the binary that holds the lock (no better than I am now). I'm wanting something a bit more in depth for managed code file lock debugging. Like a way to use WinDbg to see the call stack for the method holding the lock or similar. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This happens normally when you forgot to dispose the parent object that owns a file handle. E.g. you forgot to call Close/Dispose to a FileStream. Then the finalizer will clean up the file handles when they are no longer referenced during the next full GC.

You can check with Windbg if you have SafeFileHandles in the finalization queue ready for finalization. A profiler which can track such things is e.g. YourKit which can when you enable probes also search for files closed in the finalizer and gives you the creation call stack which gives you the ability to search in your code for the offending line.
Check out the process Inspection tab of YourKit to find the probe check.